Why can I not undo some changes in Git?
This is very silly. The code base I am working on doesn't have a gitignore, so I have to manually undo some changes before I push.
In the photo, I can undo certain changes. However, when it comes to the changes that I made installing packages, I can't. Is there a reason why this happens? Is there a git command to unstage and ignore specific changes, but not others?


Don't know about your GUI, but git reset -p in a terminal lets you interactively pick and choose which changes you want to keep and which to unstage. Maybe simpler?

If you need to unstage specific files, you can run either git restore --staged <pathspec> or git reset --mixed <pathspec>:
git restore --staged <file1>, <file2>, ..., <fileN>

# or

# the --mixed option can be omitted as it's the default behavior
git reset --mixed <file1>, <file2>, ..., <fileN>

@Romain Valeri's answer is definitely more generic and flexible, as it allows you to unstage specific hunks of changes. See git reset -p documentation for more details.
You've also talked about gitignore, but you don't have one. If you find yourself to often unstaging or resetting certain files because they shouldn't be part of your repository, consider defining a .gitignore file with the patterns of the files or directories you wish to be ignored.

You actually don't have to undo anything!
In Visual Studio, the "Changes" section shows all of your pending changes, including new files (shown with an "A" for "Add"), deleted files (shown with a "D"), and modified files (shown with a "M"). The key point about these changes are that they are unstaged.
When all of your pending changes are unstaged, Visual Studio shows a button which says "Commit All". If you enter your commit message and click that button it will first stage all of your pending changes, and then create a new commit.
But you don't have to commit all of your changes. Simply right click on any files (or folders) in the changes windows and select "Stage". Then you will notice that the commit button text changes to "Commit Staged". Then when you add your commit message and press the button it will only commit the files that you already staged. So in your case, all you have to do is stage the files you want, and you can leave all the rest untouched.
Once you stage some files, a new window section will appear called "Staged Changes", which is separate from "Changes" (which is really your unstaged changes). Before you commit, you can stage or unstage more files as you wish. When you unstage, you will move them out of "Staged Changes" and back into "Changes".
Tip: although this works, it's typically much more efficient to create a .gitignore so that you don't have to do this every time. Usually the .gitignore is also committed since others probably likely want to ignore a similar set of files as you. If you'd rather not commit your .gitignore and share it with others, then you can also make a personal copy that only affects your personal repo.
